Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are: null
I am getting this error when creating the new avd using avdmanager create command. The system image is downloaded properly but the avdmanager can't find it. Here is the output in the terminal
PS C:\Windows\system32> sdkmanager "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"
[=======================================] 100% Unzipping... x86_64/data/system/d
PS C:\Windows\system32> avdmanager create avd -n Pixel_4 -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64" -d "Pixel_4"
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...
Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:
null
I tried giving the path manually with the -k flag and still it didn't work
